# Responsive background images bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I am using bootstrap and am trying to make my background images responsive, but its just not working! Here is my code...

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg">
        <img src="../img/home_bg.jpg" alt="home background image">
    </div><!-- /.bg -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

css

```
.bg {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle please

Comment: also, one fairly obvious mistake is that <img> is not a background, so the css you have in .bg wont make a difference unless you declare a background-image in the css

Comment: Thank you... I haven't created a jsfiddle before, I'll have a look now, I'm very new to coding so bare with me!

Comment: no problem, we were all beginners once!

Comment: I added background-image: url(../img/home_bg.jpg); to my css, and took the <img...> out of the html, however it still doesn't work..

Comment: do you mind posting the jsfiddle link?

Comment: sure, http://jsfiddle.net/KeepC32/8L9Ty/

Comment: unfortunately there is no way for a background image to fill a div without setting set height/widths etc. however this is the best i could come up with given my limited time http://jsfiddle.net/8L9Ty/3/

Answer (score 15):

You need to read up a bit more about the difference between background images and inline images. You cannot style an img tag as a background, it is a block level element, and flows with the document. A background image is a property of an element. Since you want this image to be the background of the whole page, you can apply the background image to the html or body elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/8L9Ty/3/

```
body {
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/900/900');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am trying from so long, and finally I found that in bootstrap 3.3.5 you have to use the height and width property to set the background.
I used the following code:

```
.header{
    background-image: url(images/header.png); 
    height: 500px;

    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mention background image for your "DIV" tag. I assume you want to apply background image for your whole page. Is this what you looking for ?

**Stylesheet**

```
 body {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') repeat-x, repeat-y;
 }
```

**HTML Part**

```
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="bg">

</div><!-- /.bg -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AziziMusa/8L9Ty/5/

Comment: Thank you.. Yes, I want the image to fit to act as the whole background... I tried what you said and it has made the image fit properly but isn't responsive! If there is another easier way without using a div (this was just the first thing I thought of) then that would be great..

Answer (score 1):

remove the img tag `<img src="../img/home_bg.jpg" alt="home background image">` and do it with css as below :

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="bg"></div><!-- /.bg -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

css

```
.bg {
    background-image: url('../img/home_bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .bg {
                /* Full height */
                height: 100%;

                /* The image used */
                background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300");

                /* Center and scale the image nicely */
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
            }
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid bg" >

    </div>
```