# Make background images responsive using media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries

I am trying to make my background images responsive using media queries, but everything I try doesn't work! My website is a horizontal sliding site, so all the pages are defined as a section in index.html, with the background-images declared within the section tags. I am using bootstrap, however I have been told (by work) to use media queries instead of the col col.. class.
Here is my code:

```
    <section class="section home-section" data-title="home" id="home" style="left: 1278px; background-image: url(img/home_bg.jpg); background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
    <div class="main-content-home-box">
        <h1 class="title">what is cookinkits?</h1>
        <p class="main-content-home">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div><!-- /.what-is-cookinkits -->


    <div class="latest-news-box">
        <h1 class="title">check out the latest news here...</h1>
    </div>
</section><!-- /.home page -->


section.home-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

}

Comment: Just use cover without media queries, how does it look like?

Comment: Ok, tried that, the image doesn't appear at all..

Comment: Put it on Fiddle, for us to play with

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KeepC32/8ws2E/

Comment: never done a fiddle before so I hope its right! :-)

Comment: You need to apply it on the body.

Comment: You want the whole page with the background, then apply on body.

Comment: apply the image to the body? The problem is that my pages are all sections, instead of other .html pages...

Comment: Clarify further, where do you want the background to appear?

Comment: So I need the images to fill the sections, as the sections are going to be the pages... its a horizontal sliding site, so its like the pages are lined up next to each other horizontally, so its like the pages are all on a reel, and it just turns when i go to the next page... Does that help?

Comment: In your fiddle, what's the problem exactly.

Comment: the problem is that my image isn't responsive, it doesn't show at all

Comment: Update your Fiddle with a proper image and paste link

Comment: If the problem is that the image isn't appearing, then it isn't a CSS (or Sass) problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8ws2E/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive background images bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784128/responsive-background-images-bootstrap-3)